# What did a stock exchange look like 200 years ago?

Tags: stock-markets, stock-exchanges, history

Stock prices on the public exchanges fluctuate rapidly. Two hundred years ago, there wasn't a digital world to display these constantly changing prices every millisecond. What did a stock exchange look like back then? How often were prices updated? How long would it take to lock in a trade? And was there as much intraday price fluctuations for the stock market 200 years ago as there is today?

Comment: I am no stock market historian but I would assume much or all of trading was done through open outcry markets, meaning that you would presumably get as good as price as possible through negotiating that you would have delegated to a trader or broker of some sort. As such, you would probably expect quite a bit of intraday fluctuations given that trades are negotiated individually.

Comment: @ApplePie Unfortunately I can't claim to be expert enough to give an answer. But apparently semaphore systems have existed (for use in trading) since 1800s. Maybe somebody can expand on this? http://theinstitute.ieee.org/tech-history/technology-history/a-history-of-trading-speed-telescopes-telegraphs-and-fiber-optics

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about history, not personal finance.

Answer (score 2):

Before computers, the stock markets operated on trading floors. The brokers would shout on top of each others voice to find a match. There was no way to match best trades. It was the price 2 brokers would agree. With phones some amount of instructions from client could be taken.

The physical certificate would be sent to company to get new certificate in your name, often a process of few weeks to months. Frequent traders would not bother to get it changed, and keep selling... So original certificate holder enjoyed dividends quite some time after the shares were sold.

There was no price list, it was what large brokers said it was...

The S&P was manually maintained, although it was established only in 1957.

Answer (score 0):

Before computer networks, they used stock tickers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticker_tape These used telegraph technology to send records of transactions. They were printed on a long strip of paper, called "ticker tape". So the banks and investment companies had this ticker going constantly, printing out individual transactions as they happened. You often see displays that "simulate" ticket tape scrolling on the bottom of the screen during news broadcasts or financial programs.